# Autoincrement non-unique column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to create a queue system for pre-orders for our webshop. Sometimes we have more orders than stock for a few deliveries to our warehouse and I'm trying to organize so that the people that made the orders first gets their products first.

The problem comes when a customer wants to make a change to an order, by for example adding something to it. For booking purposes we then make a return of the first order to our system which creates another order, and then finally create a new order with everything on it. This causes this customer to be last in the queue list in our current system where we go by date created.

What I would like to do is to have the original queue spot be copied over to the new order without messing up the autoincrementing. This also means that there will be three orders (Original, plus return, plus new) with the same number.

```
id  | order   | queue | ordercomment
1   | 1001    | 1     | new order
2   | 1002    | 2     | new order
3   | 1003    | 3     | new order
4   | 1004    | 1     | return order 1001
5   | 1005    | 1     | corrected order 1001
6   | 1006    | 4     | new order
```

Is there any way to handle this without making a manual incrementing solution that checks for the current highest number whenever an order is made?

Comment: How about an order date, or a promised order date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where we go by date created

But your data has no such date.  You're relying on incrementing integers to determine the sort order, and that's where you're running into trouble.

If you want to sort by the date created, store the date the order was created.  Any time you modify, append, or otherwise recreate an order you can still preserve the original order date.  Perhaps with two columns, the date of the current order and the date of the original order.  (For most orders these two values would be the same, but there's nothing wrong with that.)

Then your order of priority would simply be the date of the original order.

Basically, don't try to use an integer as a timestamp.  Use a timestamp.

Comment: I apologize, I minimized the order table to what I saw as relevant fields as an example of what I was looking for. The actual table does contain creation date and quite a lot of other data as well.

Comment: @DanielNordh: Then you're already part-way there.  The point here is that the `queue` column is an artificial construct in this design.  If the intent of that column is to allow you to sort on the date of the order, then just sort on the date of the order.

Comment: One reason to go with an artificial construct is that we could potentially want to shift the queue around (something I didn't mention in my question), such as prioritize an order for a big client. But with your solution we could of course just change the queue date if we needed to, but that might look a bit messy.

It's not a bad idea though! And it would be a lot easier to create a starting point based on our current system by just copying the creation date over.

Comment: @DanielNordh: "Priority" could be its own column.  If an important client needs to get in sooner, their orders can have a higher priority value.  You can sort by priority and then by date, or further refine it with a custom algorithm which derives a value from a combination of date and priority.  The main point remains, an incrementing number is not the data you're looking for, it's the wrong tool for the job.  The design is using this number in place of natural data, such as the order date and a customer priority.  Favor the natural data and design your code around that.

Comment: In doing a test to try it out, I did run into a bit of a problem, and that is that you can't have two timestamp fields with the default being set to current timestamp. "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause".

Comment: After some workaround with setting one column as non-default and setting the value manually in the code instead, this is the option we're going to go by, hence I accepted it as an answer as it gets the job done. Thank you for your input and help!